# Can't install openvpn 2.4.x - Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn

Given:
Linux Mint 21.2

I need to install openvpn 2.4.x

I try this:

```
curl -s https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
apt update
```

And after I try to install it like this:

```
apt install -y openvpn
```

I get error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openvpn : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
           Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```